# Was there a D to TH sound change in English?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, historical-change, old-english, middle-english

I looked up the etymology of "father" and see what Etymology Dictionary [says](https://www.etymonline.com/word/father):

> *Old English **fæder*** "he who begets a child, nearest male ancestor;"

It clearly says "**fæder**" with a D.

[Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/father) also has the D version:

> From *Middle English **fader***, from *Old English **fæder***, from Proto-West Germanic *fader, from Proto-Germanic *fadēr, from Proto-Indo-European *ph₂tḗr. Doublet of ayr, faeder, padre, pater and père.

The TH was also D in middle English along with old English.

Also the word "[mother](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=mother)":

> "female parent, a woman in relation to her child," *Middle English **moder***, from *Old English **modor***

But the word "[brother](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=brother)":

> *Old English **broþor***, from Proto-Germanic *brothar (source also of Old Norse broðir, Danish broder, Old Frisian brother, Dutch broeder, Old High German bruodar, German Bruder, Gothic bróþar), from PIE root *bhrater-.

I don't know what that is, but it is not D. So the change only took place in some words.

**Can anyone explain what kind of change that was and what words it applied to?**

Comment: Also consider *[murder](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/murder#English)*, which Shakespeare sometimes spelled *murther*, and which was originally *morþor* in Old English. So the sound change from "d" to "th" happened in both directions.

Comment: @PeterShor - Interesting. Also *burden*: "Old English byrðen" (https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=burden)

Comment: ***þ*** (*thorn*) and ***ð*** (*eth*) were used interchangeably to represent both the *th* sounds in Old English.

Comment: About *burthen / burden*: Handel's Messiah (1741) ends Part the First with "His yoke is easy and his burthen is light." Modern choirs are split between which to pronounce.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [/ð/ → /d/ shift in English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141514/%c3%b0-%e2%86%92-d-shift-in-english)

Comment: I don't know whether this is relevant or not, but some tribal languages in northern Kenya distinguish between a normal or 'hard' d sound and a 'soft' d, pronounced by positioning the tip of the tongue between the teeth as if making a 'th' sound. I wonder if this may have been an intermediate stage, or if some of the Old English words spelt with a 'd' were actually pronounced in this way.

Comment: @Nams That seems definitely relevant. The D is normally made at the ridge but when the tongue moves down, it becomes TH. So I think thats what happened gradually in English. In some languages T and D are still made at the teeth (behind the teeth or between but are "plosives" like D and T)

Answer (score 6):

Grimm's law is at work here.

> Grimm's law consists of three parts which form consecutive phases in
> the sense of a chain shift. The phases are usually constructed as
> follows:
>
> Proto-Indo-European voiceless stops change into voiceless fricatives.
> Proto-Indo-European voiced stops become voiceless stops.
> Proto-Indo-European voiced aspirated stops become voiced stops or
> fricatives (as allophones). This chain shift (in the order 3,2,1) can
> be abstractly represented as:
>
> bʰ → b → p → f
>
> **dʰ → d → t → θ**
>
> gʰ → g → k → x
>
> gʷʰ → gʷ → kʷ → xʷ
>
> Here each sound moves one position to the right to take on its new
> sound value.

(Source: [Grimm's Law at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimm%27s_law))

Consider the chain shift in bold. This phenomenon is at work in the Latin *dental* to English *tooth* and in the examples cited by the OP, from Latin *pater* to OE *fæder* to English *father*.

Comment: Good Job! I searched on Google but didn't find antything or didn't understand the terminology

Comment: While Grimm's law is relevant, it doesn't answer the question of why _mother_ and _father_ had /d/ in Old English, unlike _brother_. The Indo-European root had /t/, so Grimm's law implies that Germanic should have had /θ/, not /d/.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, the originators of Grimm's Law are the brothers Grimm (of Grimm's fairy tales fame).

Comment: "dʰ → d → t → θ" /// And the [θ] to [ð] change in *father, mother* etc., was probably due to *intervocalic fricative voicing*.

Comment: Until Middle English (which was long after Grimm's Law operated), fricatives didn't distinguish voicing, so there was no real distinction between /θ/ and /ð/. They were allophones of the same phoneme with variable distribution, like the spellings. The important thing is that the stop changed to a fricative.

Comment: @Colin Verner's Law explains the change of /þ/ to /đ/ in Proto-Germanic. In West Germanic, all /đ/ became /d/, thus OE fæder.