# Why 'd' in 'Aeneid'?

Tags: etymology, history, latin, poetry, greek

The Latin poem *Aeneis* is *Aeneid* in English. How did the last *d* come about?

A few suspects by quick search:

- [/ð/ → /d/ shift in English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141514/%C3%B0-%E2%86%92-d-shift-in-english), but there must be a shift /s/ → /ð/.
- It seems romance languages write it with *d*, possibly it came from French? (German does not have *d*).

Comment: It was by analogy with the _Iliad_, which inspired it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Latin words have different forms for different grammatical [cases](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0001%3Apart%3D1%3Asection%3D6) (depending on their function in a sentence or phrase). *[Aeneis](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/Aeneis)* is the **nominative case** form of the title in Latin, but the **stem** is actually *Aeneid-.* The *-s* at the end of *Aeneis* is a nominative singular ending that causes the *d* at the end of the stem to be deleted, since Latin doesn't allow words to end in a cluster **-ds.* So the grammatical structure of the word is *Aeneid-s* which ends up as *Aeneis.* When the word has a different case in Latin, it takes other suffixes and the *d* is visible.

When a Latin word is taken into English, sometimes the nominative form is taken as-is, but sometimes a form based on the stem is used. It may depend on the details of how the word got into English. Actually, the Oxford English Dictionary says that in the case of *Aeneid,* a third type of form based on the Greek-type genitive singular *(A)eneidos* was once used in English.

Comment: Indeed so. Also see the details included in the OED’s entries on [**‑iad**, comb. form](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/236145#eid13234818) and [**‑ad**, suffix¹](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/2050), where it explains more extensively the classical origins of these forms via Latin *‑ad‑*, *‑as* and Greek *‑αδ‑*, *‑άς*,  and how we have come to use them in English.

Comment: The same happened with *Iliad* which is *Ἰλιάς* (*Iliás*) in Greek.

Comment: And *decade* from Greek *dekas*, stem *dekad-*.